# What is the best way to learn about gene regulation?

Tags: gene-expression, book-recommendation, gene-regulation

For those of you who already have a decent knowledge of how gene regulation works, how should someone new to the topic acquire a detailed overview?

Is there a particularly good and up-to-date resource?
Is it better to learn from the primary literature? If so, what are the main sub-topics within gene regulation to cover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not learn from the primary literature, the terminology will likely be confusing and there will be a tendency to conflate whatever the current methods are with the concepts.

I'd suggest going for a basic introductory course in the topic, or a textbook. [Here is a resource from NHGRI](https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/Gene-Regulation) which may be helpful as an introduction.

[Here is an online textbook section](https://openstax.org/books/biology-2e/pages/16-introduction) that might handle the topic at a very basic level. [Here is an online version](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26818/) of a traditional standard text at the undergraduate level.

Probably the best somewhat more technical introduction to the basic concepts, without a lot of the fuss, is [Mark Ptashne's classic 1986 book on phage lambda](https://www.cshlpress.com/default.tpl?cart=1698349449364209542&fromlink=T&linkaction=full&linksortby=oop_title&--eqSKUdatarq=468).

I saw Ptashne give a talk in the mid 2010s in which he declared (somewhat pompously) that we still didn't understand anything in gene regulation other than phage lambda. No one contradicted him, and I don't think that anyone would contradict him if he said the same thing today.